# What is wrong with my code for euler 7?

Tags: python

Why is this not working for euler problem:https://projecteuler.net/problem=7

```
def primeornot(n):
    counter=0
    if n==2:
        return True
    else:
        for number in range(2,n):
            if not n%number:
                counter=1
        if counter ==1:
            return False
        if counter==0:
                return True


primes=[]
m=2
while len(primes)<10002:
     if primeornot(m) is True:
        primes.append(m)
        m=m+1
     else:
        m=m+1
print (primes[10000])
```

[No syntax error] I have edited it
Primeornot looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add a progressbar to your code, so we can see how quickly we get to the answer.

```
import progressbar

p = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[progressbar.SimpleProgress(), ' ', progressbar.ETA()], maxval=10002)
p.start()

while len(primes) < 10002:
    p.update(len(primes))
    if primeornot(m) is True:
        primes.append(m)
        m=m+1
    else:
        m=m+1
```

By doing this, we can see that your current implementation is just **too slow** for this problem. You need a **better algorithm**. In general, I'd suggest implementing something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

### Alternatively...

On the other hand, perhaps we could make a smaller adjustment to your program to fix the issue. Let's look at your `primeornot()` function.

Once we've found an actual divisor of a number, we don't need to test the remaining numbers available. Instead, we could return early. So we could do:

```
def primeornot(n):
    for number in xrange(2,n):
        if n % number == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Additionally, we know that the largest possible divisor of a number is the [square root of that number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102755/greatest-prime-factor-of-n-is-less-than-square-root-of-n-proof). So we can add that optimization as well:

```
def primeornot(n):
    maximum = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1

    for number in xrange(2, maximum):
        if n % number == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This causes the code to run in less than a second for me, and produces the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem this can't work is the **conditional in your while loop.  You're breaking after you have found 100 primes, but you need to find the 10001st prime.**

So this line:

```
while len(primes) < 100:
```

means that whenever you have found 100 prime numbers, you will exit the while loop.  I'll clarify more if you need it; just let me know.

Comment: sorry. it was my mistake while editing. I will edit it again. The problem is still unsolved.

Comment: even primes[0] is empty